# Throttling Tasks competing for execution (under the hood)

Tags: .net, async-await

Consider a Microsoft .NET Framework application that takes full advantage of the async/await facilities to produce many simultaneous (or also nested) tasks. There's no significant "flow" control, i.e. the tasks are mostly independent, not waiting each other to complete, thus all competing for execution.

What is the framework component that makes the decision how/when to scheduling or execute a Task and on which thread?

What are possible courses to influence that mechanism from user code?

**EDIT**
I [found](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/06/15/executioncontext-vs-synchronizationcontext.aspx) a good sentence that pin-points where my question is aimed at:

*Whenever code awaits an awaitable whose awaiter says it’s not yet complete (i.e. the awaiter’s IsCompleted returns false), the method needs to suspend ...*

The point in time described here is one step late after my question - something has already processed the user code, constructed the *awaitable* and the *awaiter*, likely captured the context and decided which thread will execute (or is executing already) the task. I am asking about that "something".

I do see how user-code influences the route the framework takes, but those are external, "educated" decisions on programmer's part. Suppose we take each of the possible routes we can influence and over-saturate it... we are hitting hard some facility, right? Maybe there's no one-sentence answer... And I am sorry if I am slow to see it in @Stephen's answer below - I appreciate your help and keep digging.

(Some of the relevant topics seem to go deeper under the sync/await abstracts, like thread pool, contexts. Am I to dig in that direction?) 

**END EDIT**

Are custom TaskScheduler the (best)(only) answer?

For the purpose of the question, I disregard any external considerations for throttling, like resource starvation (network, I/O saturation) or business reasons (artificial restrictions). Or hack-user-code throttling by trying to track what is executing, etc.

Comment: `TaskSheduler`s are pretty much useless for throttling `async` `Task`s (unless you only want to throttle the non-asynchronous parts). Could you explain more about what you're trying to do and why do you want to throttle the `Task`s?

Comment: @svick, I view the user code as a pump that is producing Tasks (requests to run them). Something in the framework is making the decision "I will run this task on the same thread, because ...", or "I will spawn a thread, because...". If you see flaws in my thinking - that's what I am trying to iron - I am trying to learn - imagine less and know more.

Comment: Regarding your edit: every `async` method begins executing *synchronously*; it only becomes *asynchronous* when it hits its first `await` (where `!IsCompleted`). So to schedule that first part of the method, just use a `TaskFactory` with a custom `TaskScheduler`.

Comment: It sounds like what you're really looking for is some introductory `async` material. I recommend reading (in order): [my intro](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html), the [MSDN overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx), the [TAP document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175.aspx), and the [FAQ](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/04/12/10293335.aspx).

Comment: @Stephen - thanks about the "RE:your edit" comment - so the "thing" under the hood, that acted on that "first `await` was the TaskFactory implementation? Are you able to zero on particular method or class of methods?

Comment: I have been reading intros and not just intros, including many of your blogs - thanks! But questions pop because of implicit or implied references to things under the hood. Take this as an example: you say *"The "async" keyword enables the "await" keyword in that method. That's all the async keyword does!"*(in your intro article) But that causes a slew of questions, like "why is that needed?", "what the compiler does differently for methods it's been "hinted" that an await is coming?" This is off topic - just showing why the digging.

Comment: @G.Stoynev: I don't get what you're asking about `TaskFactory`. The first portion of an `async` method is always executed synchronously. Think of it this way: `await A();` is the exact same thing as `var task = A(); await task;`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26339/discussion-between-g-stoynev-and-stephen-cleary)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> simultaneous (also parent-child related) tasks.

When one `async` method calls another method, those tasks can be thought of as a "parent/child" relationship. Technically, however, there is not a [parent/child task relationship](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997417.aspx).

> What is the framework component that control scheduling, threading, execution?

This is described in the [MSDN docs (under "Suspending Execution with Await")](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873173.aspx) as well as in [my `async`/`await` intro](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html). When an `async` method suspends itself via an `await`, by default it will capture the current `SynchronizationContext` (or the current `TaskScheduler` if there is no current `SynchronizationContext`) and use that to resume the method. This is the *default* behavior; any `async` method may choose *not* to resume on its captured context by `await`ing the result of `ConfigureAwait(false)`. In the vast majority of cases, this will execute the continuation of the method on the thread pool.

The first thing you should consider is to apply `ConfigureAwait(false)` everywhere you can. If you do this consistently, your continuations are for the most part managed by the thread pool, which makes optimum use of the resources available. Manual throttling shouldn't really be necessary.

That said, there are a few ways to do it.

**TaskScheduler**

You can use a `TaskScheduler` to control the execution of the `async` continuations (as long as they *don't* use `ConfigureAwait(false)`). [`ConcurrentExclusiveSchedulerPair` can be used for throttling or mutual exclusion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.concurrentexclusiveschedulerpair.aspx) at this level of scheduling. However, as @svick pointed out, task schedulers only "see" the individual (synchronous) *parts* of each `async` method. So this is often not the solution people are looking for.

**TPL Dataflow**

If you're mainly interested in throttling coarse-grained operations (that can have however many "child" operations as they need), you can do that using an `ActionBlock` from [TPL Dataflow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603.aspx):

```
var block = new ActionBlock<Func<Task>>(f => f(),
    new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = ...; });
block.Post(MyMethodAsync);
...
```

Unlike the `TaskScheduler` approach, the `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` of TPL Dataflow does consider the `async` method as a whole, including all its "child" tasks and continuations.

Once you start using TPL Dataflow, you may find that other portions of your app's logic are more naturally expressed with it as well.

**AsyncSemaphore**

If your throttling needs are more complex, another approach is [`AsyncSemaphore`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/02/12/10266983.aspx), [available in my AsyncEx library](http://nitoasyncex.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=AsyncSemaphore). Each of your `async` methods that needs to be throttled would then start its execution with `await WaitAsync` and complete with `Release`. You have full control over the scope of what's throttled by placing these calls where you choose.

Comment: I edited the question - didn't mean to refer to such parent-child, but rather the nesting of Tasks. Not so relevant anyway. See my comment to svick's comment RE: the nature of my question. I can see many references to throttling by using specialized TaskSchedulers, your TPL Dataflow reference, etc., but those are always backed by programmer's decision. My question seeks for the understanding and knowledge that will help with such decision. Very small example - it's great that I can set degree of parallelism, but what value? I have taken the approach to study this from the grounds up.

Comment: See the first part of my answer for a description of how `async` works with scheduling primitives and the thread pool.